# Reverse Keyup function for search form

Tags: html, jquery, keyup, onkeyup

I have a small lottery search form comprising of 6 input fields. Once the user enters a number, it moves to the next field using a Jquery keyup function.

How can I add a reverse event, so when I delete a number using the delete button, it moves to the previous field?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#target input").keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
      $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
    } else if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
      var new_val = $(this).val().substring(1, 2);
      $(this).val(new_val);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_1" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_2" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_2" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_3" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_3" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_4" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_4" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_5" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_5" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_6" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_6" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="search-ticket" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - next time just post the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a check for the backspace key as the first statement in your if/else if/else block:

```
if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
  $(this).prev('input').focus();
} else if {
  // Rest of your logic here
}
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#target input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
      $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
    } else if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
      $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
    } else if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
      var new_val = $(this).val().substring(1, 2);
      $(this).val(new_val);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_1" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_2" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_2" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_3" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_3" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_4" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_4" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_5" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_5" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <input type="number" id="keyword_6" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_6" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
  <button class="btn btn-info" id="search-ticket" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixes the backspace event If I move to the first input. However, if I do not backspace to the first input, I am unable to proceed forward by entering the search value as originally.

Comment: @P.Sav Ah, if that's what you want, then you need to also reset the value in the previous input, i.e. `$(this).prev('input').val('').focus();`. Updated the code snippet too.

Answer (score 1):

Detect the keycode of the `keyup` event, if the keycode is backspace (should be `"event.keyCode == 8"`) and the input is empty fire focus on the previous input.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#target input").keyup(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
            $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
        } else if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
            var new_val = $(this).val().substring(1, 2);
            $(this).val(new_val);
            $(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
        } else if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            if ($(this).prev('input')) {
                $(this).prev('input').focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_1" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_2" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_2" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_3" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_3" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_4" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_4" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_5" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_5" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <input type="number" id="keyword_6" maxlength="1" min="0" max="9" name="keyword_6" style="width: 35px !important; etter-spacing: 1.5px;">
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="search-ticket" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Honestly I would change a lot of your code.

To mantain your code you could change the function like this:
 I EDITED COMMENT TO ADD CODE

Comment: Thank you- but this does not allow me to backspace unless begin from input 1. If I change a value mid-search, I am unable to move forward as originally.

Comment: If i understood what you mean now I edited the snipped to fix it.